# Using where clause with a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my app I have a search field to find football visits. I want it to be able to search by the club of the visit. In my model visit belongs_to club, so visit has a field "club_id". So when I search with an ID, it finds the club, but I want to be able to find it by club name. "club_id" should be replaces by something like "visit.club.name", but how can I achieve this? This is my current query:

```
  # Find visits
  def find_anything(find_phrase)
    unless find_phrase.blank?
      @visits = Visit.where('address LIKE ? OR ground LIKE ? OR club_id LIKE ?',
                "%#{find_phrase}%",
                "%#{find_phrase}%",
                "%#{find_phrase}%")
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should do the trick:

```
Visit.where(club_id: Club.where(name: "ClubName"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Club.joins(:visits).where('visits.club_id' => club_id).first.name
```

*this assumes the Club model has_many :visits

or

```
    Club.find(Visit.find_by_club_id(club_id)).name
```